# Can I build libpostal on one machine and transfer the binaries to another?

Tags: compilation

I'm trying to build libpostal on a Digital Ocean machine. The machine has 1Gb RAM, and this seems to make the build impossible (gcc gets killed).

Is it possible to build libpostal on another machine (also Digital Ocean), and then transfer the binaries? and how would that be done?

Does the data directory (`datadir` in the configure step) also need to be transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you try the docker, which will relieve you from all these things, OS independent.

https://github.com/johnlonganecker/libpostal-rest-docker

I am using the docker and use the REST api to hit the parser